# Case disappears from queue after assigned to support user

Tags: case, queue

My organization has a handful of support queues based on the type of issue received.  A new queue was recently established for a new area of support.  In the new LibRel queue, when a support staff member initially opens the (email to case created) case to assign to the proper account and staff member, saves the changes - the case is no longer visible in that queue.  The staff member may see the case in their open cases; however the case is no longer displayed in the LibRel queue.

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work? Queue = unclaimed work, you pick from it (changing the owner to yourself), work on the case and then maybe leave it (closed?) with you or change the owner back to the queue... Depends on how your organisation works.

Comment: Our organization has both, case queue and case owner.  In our other queues, you can see all cases (open/closed based on filters) regardless of the case owner - simply based on the queue the case belongs.  However, this is not the same in the newest queue.

Comment: Is your "Case Owner" a custom field? A lookup to User object perhaps? In that... case... we were talking about the standard Owner field, labeled as `Lookup(User,Queue)`. I don't think it's possible to make a lookup to Queue... Or perhaps your "Queue" is a custom field? Some picklist?

Answer (score 3):

A Queue is an owner of a case. As soon as the case is reassigned, then the queue no longer owns the case so it would make sense that it's no longer visible in that view. From the documentation (emphasis added):

> Queues help your teams manage leads, cases, service contracts, and custom objects. Once records are placed in a queue manually or through an automatic case or lead assignment rule, records remain there ***until they're assigned to a user or taken by one of the queue members***. Any queue member or users above them in the role hierarchy can take ownership of records in a queue.

Comment: Right. `Assigning a Case to a User` is another way to say `Changing the Owner on a Case`. There can only ever be one Owner of a record.

Comment: Our organization has both, case queue and case owner.  In our other queues, you can see all cases (open/closed based on filters) regardless of the case owner - simply based on the queue the case belongs.  However, this is not the same in the newest queue.

Comment: Sounds like you have something pretty customized then and we'd need a lot more info, like how your List Views are structured to unravel why this is happening.